# Zeit, can it not exist?

Tags: time

Imagine a person, Mr. T, for whom it *doesn't matter* what *time* he arrives at a particular destination D. So *it's the same* whether Mr. T is at D at 5 AM or 6 PM or on Monday or Tuesday or in Jan or August or in 1978 BC or in 3024 AD or any other imaginable time stamp.

Does time *exist* for Mr. T?

Comment: please formulate the title of your question as... a question. It will help browsing questions and attract better answers.

Comment: Where does an 800 pound gorilla sit? *Anywhere he wants to.*

Comment: What does "exist for" mean? We might imagine that Mr. T doesn't care about time, but that time still has an effect on what happens such that Mr. T figures in the happening of it (if someone *else* cares about when Mr. T arrives at some destination, say, time should exist for the conglomerate of Mr. T and the other person).

Comment: *Ex vulgus scientia*, x exists for y if y *matters* to x (vagueness unintended, but you should be able to find an appropriate idea that makes sense to you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine Mr.T doesn't care about what he eats - french fries, donuts, steak, doesn't matter - any meal is as good as the other. Despite this, he still feels hungry and desires food - it's just that any element of the set "edible things" will do :)

To be indifferent to elements of some class C doesn't mean C doesn't exist, it simply means ∀ x,y ∈ Food: ¬(x>y ∨ x<y).